# Are EU members answerable to the ECtHR?

Tags: european-union

Do EU members need to be answerable to the [ECtHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Court_of_Human_Rights)?

The ECHR and its court are distinct to the EU, but is membership of the EU in any way tied to the rulings of this organisation?

Comment: Yes, the ECtHR oversees the ECHR, which is a requirement for membership.

Comment: Thank you. So when Theresa May said that the United Kingdom should leave the ECHR in 2016, while advocating for Remain, can you explain what she was envisaging?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Do you have a reference for the requirement for EU member states to abide by this court?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, EU members must follow [ECtHR](https://www.echr.coe.int/Pages/home.aspx?p=home&c=) rulings. The ECtHR is one of the bodies of the [Council of Europe](https://www.coe.int/en/web/portal/home) and is meant to enforce the [European Convention on Human Rights](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/005).

And [in fact](https://www.coe.int/en/web/about-us/do-not-get-confused):

> No country has ever joined the EU without first belonging to the
>   Council of Europe.

The [EU is itself a contracting party to the convention](https://www.echr.coe.int/Pages/home.aspx?p=basictexts/accessionEU&c) and:

> **What is the current status of the ECHR and the Strasbourg case-law in**
>   **EU law?**
>
> (...)
>
> The present situation is that the rights enshrined in the ECHR are not
>   legally binding on the EU and its institutions (Commission, Council,
>   European Parliament, Court of Justice etc.). **However, these rights do**
>   **apply to the EU member States, even when the latter are applying or**
>   **implementing EU law.** This creates an imbalance which can lead to
>   uncertainty and confusion about who, ultimately, is responsible for
>   any breaches of ECHR rights.
>
> (...)

The reference in treaty can be found in the [Article 6 of the Treaty of Lisbon](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-european-union-and-comments/title-1-common-provisions/8-article-6.html) where ECHR rights are considered to constitute the principles for EU law.

> (...)
>
> 3. Fundamental rights, as guaranteed by the European Convention for the Protection of Human Rights and Fundamental Freedoms and as they
>      result from the constitutional traditions common to the Member States,
>      shall constitute general principles of the Union's law.

Answer (score 4):

> **is membership of the EU in any way tied to the rulings of this organisation?**

Nobody really knows yet?

---

The BBC [covered this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-eu-referendum-36149798) in April 2016

> If the UK wanted to stay in the EU but leave the ECHR, the European Commission would have to decide whether that meant the UK had too little respect for human rights to stay in the Union. Nobody has tried it before and lawyers disagree about what the Commission's conclusion would be.

---

[The European Parliament Think Tank](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/thinktank/en/document.html?reference=EPRS_BRI%282017%29607298) suggests that the two are not yet completely or irrevocably bound together.

> **The Treaty of Lisbon** provided for a duty of the EU to accede to the ECHR. However, when the negotiated agreement was put to the Court of Justice for opinion, it ruled (in December 2015) that the agreement **did not provide for** sufficient protection of the EU's specific legal arrangements and **the Court's exclusive jurisdiction**. For the time being, no new accession agreement has been drafted, but both the Parliament and the Commission underline the need for EU accession.

(my emphasis)